# rbenv path : no such file or directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I've recently installed the `libvips` (https://www.libvips.org/install.html) image processing library and this has caused some conflicts running Jekyll on my local environment. *The installation had `rbenv` upgraded from version `1.1.2` to `1.2.0`.*

#### The error I'm getting is:

```
/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/shims/jekyll: line 21: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec/rbenv: No such file or directory
```

#### My `rbenv.log` file:

```
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:23): enable -f /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-realpath.dylib realpath
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:54): '[' -z '' ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:55): RBENV_ROOT=/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:59): export RBENV_ROOT
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:61): '[' -z '' ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:62): RBENV_DIR=/Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:69): export RBENV_DIR
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:71): '[' -n '' ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:71): export RBENV_ORIG_PATH=/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/shims:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:71): RBENV_ORIG_PATH=/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/shims:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:73): shopt -s nullglob
++(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:75): abs_dirname /opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv
++(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:25): abs_dirname(): local path
+++(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:26): abs_dirname(): realpath /opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv
++(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:26): abs_dirname(): path=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv
++(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:27): abs_dirname(): echo /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:75): bin_path=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:79): export PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/shims:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:79): PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/shims:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:81): RBENV_HOOK_PATH=:/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/rbenv.d
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:82): '[' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0 '!=' /Users/gschiavon/.rbenv ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:84): RBENV_HOOK_PATH=:/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/rbenv.d:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/rbenv.d
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:86): RBENV_HOOK_PATH=:/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/rbenv.d:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/rbenv.d:/opt/homebrew/etc/rbenv.d:/usr/local/etc/rbenv.d:/etc/rbenv.d:/usr/lib/rbenv/hooks
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:90): RBENV_HOOK_PATH=/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/rbenv.d:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/rbenv.d:/opt/homebrew/etc/rbenv.d:/usr/local/etc/rbenv.d:/etc/rbenv.d:/usr/lib/rbenv/hooks
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:91): export RBENV_HOOK_PATH
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:93): shopt -u nullglob
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:96): command=version
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:97): case "$command" in
++(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:110): command -v rbenv-version
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:110): command_path=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:111): '[' -z /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:119): shift 1
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:120): '[' '' = --help ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv:127): exec /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version
++(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version:11): rbenv-version-name
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:6): '[' -z '' ']'
++(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:7): rbenv-version-file
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:7): target_dir=
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:22): '[' -n '' ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:25): find_local_version_file /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:10): find_local_version_file(): local root=/Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell/.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:17): find_local_version_file(): root=/Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:17): find_local_version_file(): root=/Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:17): find_local_version_file(): root=/Users/gschiavon/Documents
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ /Users/gschiavon/Documents =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /Users/gschiavon/Documents/.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n /Users/gschiavon/Documents ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:17): find_local_version_file(): root=/Users/gschiavon
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ /Users/gschiavon =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /Users/gschiavon/.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n /Users/gschiavon ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:17): find_local_version_file(): root=/Users
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ /Users =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /Users/.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n /Users ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:17): find_local_version_file(): root=
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ '' =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n '' ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): break
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:19): find_local_version_file(): return 1
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:26): '[' /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell '!=' /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:27): echo /Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/version
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:7): RBENV_VERSION_FILE=/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/version
++(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:8): rbenv-version-file-read /Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/version
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file-read:6): VERSION_FILE=/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/version
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file-read:8): '[' -e /Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file-read:10): IFS='   

'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file-read:11): words=($(cut -b 1-1024 "$VERSION_FILE"))
++(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file-read:11): cut -b 1-1024 /Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/version
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file-read:12): version=3.0.0
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file-read:14): '[' 3.0.0 = .. ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file-read:14): [[ 3.0.0 == */* ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file-read:16): '[' -n 3.0.0 ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file-read:17): echo 3.0.0
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file-read:18): exit
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:8): RBENV_VERSION=3.0.0
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:11): OLDIFS='     
'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:12): IFS='
'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:12): scripts=(`rbenv-hooks version-name`)
++(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:12): rbenv-hooks version-name
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:9): '[' version-name = --complete ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:18): RBENV_COMMAND=version-name
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:19): '[' -z version-name ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:24): enable -f /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-realpath.dylib realpath
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:55): IFS=:
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:55): hook_paths=($RBENV_HOOK_PATH)
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:57): shopt -s nullglob
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:58): for path in '"${hook_paths[@]}"'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:58): for path in '"${hook_paths[@]}"'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:58): for path in '"${hook_paths[@]}"'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:58): for path in '"${hook_paths[@]}"'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:58): for path in '"${hook_paths[@]}"'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:58): for path in '"${hook_paths[@]}"'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:63): shopt -u nullglob
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:13): IFS='    
'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:18): '[' -z 3.0.0 ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:18): '[' 3.0.0 = system ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:28): version_exists 3.0.0
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:24): version_exists(): local version=3.0.0
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:25): version_exists(): '[' -d /Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0 ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-name:29): echo 3.0.0
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version:11): version_name=3.0.0
++(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version:12): rbenv-version-origin
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-origin:6): unset RBENV_VERSION_ORIGIN
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-origin:8): OLDIFS='    
'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-origin:9): IFS='
'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-origin:9): scripts=(`rbenv-hooks version-origin`)
++(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-origin:9): rbenv-hooks version-origin
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:9): '[' version-origin = --complete ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:18): RBENV_COMMAND=version-origin
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:19): '[' -z version-origin ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:24): enable -f /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-realpath.dylib realpath
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:55): IFS=:
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:55): hook_paths=($RBENV_HOOK_PATH)
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:57): shopt -s nullglob
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:58): for path in '"${hook_paths[@]}"'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:58): for path in '"${hook_paths[@]}"'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:58): for path in '"${hook_paths[@]}"'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:58): for path in '"${hook_paths[@]}"'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:58): for path in '"${hook_paths[@]}"'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:58): for path in '"${hook_paths[@]}"'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks:63): shopt -u nullglob
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-origin:10): IFS='  
'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-origin:15): '[' -n '' ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-origin:17): '[' -n '' ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-origin:20): rbenv-version-file
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:7): target_dir=
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:22): '[' -n '' ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:25): find_local_version_file /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:10): find_local_version_file(): local root=/Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell/.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:17): find_local_version_file(): root=/Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:17): find_local_version_file(): root=/Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:17): find_local_version_file(): root=/Users/gschiavon/Documents
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ /Users/gschiavon/Documents =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /Users/gschiavon/Documents/.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n /Users/gschiavon/Documents ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:17): find_local_version_file(): root=/Users/gschiavon
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ /Users/gschiavon =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /Users/gschiavon/.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n /Users/gschiavon ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:17): find_local_version_file(): root=/Users
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ /Users =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /Users/.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n /Users ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:17): find_local_version_file(): root=
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:11): find_local_version_file(): [[ '' =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:12): find_local_version_file(): '[' -s /.ruby-version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): '[' -n '' ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:16): find_local_version_file(): break
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:19): find_local_version_file(): return 1
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:26): '[' /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell '!=' /Users/gschiavon/Documents/dev/sites.nosync/kyle-campbell ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file:27): echo /Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/version
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version:12): version_origin=/Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/version
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version:14): '[' /Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/version = /Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version:14): '[' '!' -e /Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/version ']'
+(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version:17): echo '3.0.0 (set by /Users/gschiavon/.rbenv/version)'
```

I suspect this is happening due to `rbenv` being updated to version `1.2.0` in the process of `libvips` installation.

**How can I change the `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv` path to `1.1.2`?**

Comment: Solved by running `rbenv rehash`

Comment: Verified, `rbenv rehash` saved my day!